# implementing factory method in Java

Tags: java, rx-java2, factory-pattern

TypeMap.java

```
@Data
public class TypeMap {
    private String mid;
    private Boolean allowSend;
    private List<TypeMapDetails> typeMapDetails = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

TypeMapFactory.java

```
public TypeMap createNowMessage(Boolean allowSend) {
    TypeMap typeMap = new TypeMap();
    typeMap.setMid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    typeMap.setAllowSend(allowSend);
    return typeMap;
}
```

MessageService.java

```
private Single<TypeMap> createNowMessageTemp(String message) {
    TypeMap typeMap = new TypeMapFactory().createNowMessage();
    TypeMapDetails typeMapDetails = new TypeMapDetailsFactory().createSmsDetail(typeMap.getMid(), message);
}
```

In the TypeMapFactory, I have dynamically passed the boolean `allowSend` value to the `typeMap.setAllowSend()` method.

I need to pass this boolean value to the MessageService. I know I can get the value from using `typeMap.getAllowSend()`, however I cannot pass this method into `createNowMessage();`.

In the MessageService I was able to use the `typeMap.getMid()` method but I am unable to use it in the `createNowMessage()` method in the MessageService. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. You want to pass the `allowSend` value to `createNowMessage()` call in MessageService? Where do you get the value from and what's stopping you from passing it to the method?

Comment: I dynamically pass the value from the TypeMapFactory method parameter (see TypeMapFactory.java),which contains the setallowsend() method. From here i want to pass this value into my messageServices, but  i do not know how.